# Хочу на сайте сделать слайдер одежды (кофта и штаны) . Вроде JS код в порядке но не показывает картинки и в консоли пишет net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="slider">
  <button id="last-image"><</button>
  <img id="slide-image">
  <button id="next-image">></button>
</div>
```

А вот JS:

```
var showLastImage = document.getElementById('last-image');
var showNextImage = document.getElementById('next-image');
var slideImage = document.getElementById('slide-image');


showLastImage.addEventListener('click' , onShowLastImage);
showNextImage.addEventListener('click' , onShowNextImage);


var photos = [];
photos.push("https://images.shafastatic.net/215269769");
photos.push('https://content.rozetka.com.ua/goods/images/big/181856869.jpg');

var currentNumberArray = 0;
showLastImage.disabled = true;

slideImage.src = [currentNumberArray];


function onShowLastImage() {
currentNumberArray--;
slideImage.src = [currentNumberArray];
if (currentNumberArray === 0) {
    showLastImage.disabled=true;
}
showNextImage.disabled = false;
}
function onShowNextImage() {
currentNumberArray++;
slideImage.src = [currentNumberArray];
if (currentNumberArray === (photos.length -1)) {
    showNextImage.disabled = true;
}
showLastImage.disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var showLastImage = document.getElementById('last-image');
var showNextImage = document.getElementById('next-image');
var slideImage = document.getElementById('slide-image');


showLastImage.addEventListener('click' , onShowLastImage);
showNextImage.addEventListener('click' , onShowNextImage);


var photos = [];
photos.push("https://images.shafastatic.net/215269769");
photos.push('https://content.rozetka.com.ua/goods/images/big/181856869.jpg');

var currentNumberArray = 0;
showLastImage.disabled = true;

slideImage.src = photos[currentNumberArray];


function onShowLastImage() {
currentNumberArray--;
slideImage.src = [currentNumberArray];
if (currentNumberArray === 0) {
    showLastImage.disabled=true;
}
showNextImage.disabled = false;
}
function onShowNextImage() {
currentNumberArray++;
slideImage.src = photos[currentNumberArray];
if (currentNumberArray === (photos.length -1)) {
    showNextImage.disabled = true;
}
showLastImage.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ТЕБЕ ДОБРЫЙ ЧЕЛОВЕК  ДАЙ БОГ ТЕБЕ И ТВОИМ БЛИЗКИМ ЗДОРОВЬЯ ОООЧЕНЬ ПОМОГ

Comment: @DavidShahmatov Не забудь поставить галочку возле ответа, и тебе хорошего вечера